# GroovyClassLoader doesn't work properly with cyrillic symbols

Tags: groovy

I created a simple interface and groovy script that implements this interface.

```
class groovyClass implements MySimpleInterface {
     @Override
     String description (){
        return "Описание";
     }
}
```

But when I call this function from groovy class loader I get just a couple of unknown symbols (like this :РЁРёСЂРѕРєР°СЏ СЌР) instead of my cyrillic one.

I'm using Intellij Idea

Also, when I'm writing it directly `new Label ("Описание")` it works just fine, but when I'm requesting it from groovy class loader it doesn't work

Comment: that's UTF-8 encoding. just configure properly your IDE

Comment: Groovy has extensive tests around handling different encodings. The GroovyClassLoaded works just fine.  As @daggett says, the issue lies either with your encoding in the IDE, or the encoding of your OS